# Is it possible to do Animation on views purely in XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, animation

I am trying to add animation to some Image View in an android app but I was wondering if it is possible to add animation without any java code using only XML.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my knowledge its not possible to use only xml for animation you can write a xml file inside anim folder to perform different animation and use that xml inside an activity with the help of java code
>   [You can go through this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)